# How to display page content AFTER the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a problem on my page. I have a LOT of content that I want to display to the user in a jQuery table. However while the page is loading the table shows ALL rows and the page is going to be like 10000 rows long instead of 10 (and pagination).

So I'd like to hide the table until it loads all the data (maybe put a loading image there), and when it has loaded I'd like to display the table with its loaded contents.

How can I do this?

Comment: See [ask]. and http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: http://datatables.net/ - table plugin that can do what you need/want

Comment: To be honest I'm actually using Datatables. But I want it to hide till the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I usualy apply the style "display:none" to the target container, then you can use the .load() function and use the callback to show your container filled with data.

Basically :

```
$('#target').hide();
$('#target').addClass("loading-layer");
$('#target').load('toto.php',function(){
    $('#target').removeClass("loading-layer");
    $('#target').show();
});
```

**EDIT**

I have just tried this morning to display a datatable only after loading, and you can do that way :

```
    <div id="data-container" class="hidden">
        <table id="table-courses" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display  ex_highlight data-table table-font" >
            ...
        </table>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $('#data-container').show();
        //Data table creation     
        oTable = $('#my-table').dataTable({                       
            "bJQueryUI": true
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Your container is not containing your data?

Comment: I have a DIV which contains the table (it's ID is: list). Here is my code I've made:
$('#list').hide();
$('#list').load('pointlist.php',function(){
    $('#list').show();
});

So I've actually just added this to my code and its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the table so it isn't rendered by the browser in the beginning (or even while loading):

```
<table id="data" style="display:none;">
```

(Note that this makes your page unusable to non-js users, maybe the following would be better:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    document.write("<style>hidden { display:none; }</style>");
]]></script>
<table id="data" class="hidden">
```

Then, as soon as the table is loaded (`onDOMready`), you can remove some columns dynamically, and show the rest after that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// wait for images and other included objects to load, use
// $(window).load(function() {
    var table = $("#data");
    table.startPageViewer(); // or whatever

    table.show();
    // or, respectively:
    table.removeClass("hidden");
});
```

You might also create the whole table dynamically, and serve the data in a shorter (non-HTML) format which fastens the loading, especially if done asynchronous in parallel.

Btw: You mentioned pagination - that would be much better than loading all the data at the same time.

Comment: Its already done. And how to show it when the page is loaded? Thats my problem actually.

Comment: Yeah, but its a paginated table actually :/ I can't edit it to because its JS and there is nothing to do with PHP. It loads all the data unfortunately

Comment: Is there any method that hide the whole div till the page loads? I would just simply need that.

Comment: For such large datasets, you should really use serverside (or hybrid) [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). However, the methods I've described in my answer *do* hide everything until it is loaded.

Comment: Yes they hide, but its not actually good for someone who has javascript disabled browser. I want to handle everything from javascript, hiding, and revealing the content aswell. If someone has javascript disabled, than he'll see the data in the original way.

Comment: He will. Just use the approach with the `hidden` class, where the style for it would be inserted dynamically - only if js is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/hfUSg/1/
Remove class with 'display: none' from body after page load using:

```
$("window").load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

As for javascript disabled browsers:

```
<noscript>
    <style>        
        .preloader {display: block;}
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got trapped in FOUC(Flash of Unstyled Content)

A typical way of overcoming this is to set the div containing your table to be

visibility: hidden; while the dom is still getting processed in the browser,once done at

document ready you unhide your div back

```
$('#customtabs').css('visibility','visible');
```

You can see this [example](http://fundapass.blogspot.in/2012/06/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo_22.html)